# How to Change row item size of recyclerview in full screen in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I am using recyclerview to create list row. Each row has a framelayout that load dynamic fragment that contain video player to play video, when user click on row item.
It is working fine. Now i want that during video playing, when user rotate mobile from portrait to landscape video will be display in full screen and when user rotate from landscape to portrait mode video will be play as usual in list row.
Can it possible to change size of individual row in full screen? Or other alternative method to achieve above functionality.
Below is item row xml file

```
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnailView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/videoViewContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should consider **different** approach, 
You can have separate layout for landscape mode which will only **contain single full screen video player**.

You can store current video player data like **url** and **current time** in video to `ViewModel`,
When user rotates the device, you can play the video for url you saved in ViewModel (Or any static member)

In this case you need to handle `RecyclerView` **initialization** based on current **device orientation** in `Java` or `Kotlin` code of your Activity

As when device is rotated your `onCreate()` is going to get **called again** anyway so you can handle portrait and landscape device rotation in that itself.